# Spring Boot Local Dependencies with my remote repository

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have two microservices (A and B) and i have another maven project (C) where i have a commom code for all microservices, like utils, validations, whatever ... for one reason: not replicate code.

What is the best way to add maven Project C dependency on MicroService's pom.xml and reuse code?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If it is separated repositories (maven projects) then as a dependency:

```xml
<dependecy>
    <groupId>your.project.C</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-C</artifactId>
</dependecy>
```